# Cloudinary Could not decode base64 when uploading image (size: 1mb or higher)

Tags: express, file-upload, base64, mern, cloudinary

I need some help ,I am working on the React app, I'm having trouble uploading photos to Cloudinary using MERN stack "Could not decode base64"
Note: I am currently using the free version.

```
exports.newProduct = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {  
       let imagesExterieur = [];
       // handle images external
       if (typeof req.body.imagesExterieur === 'string') {
        imagesExterieur.push(req.body.imagesExterieur)
    } else {
        imagesExterieur = req.body.imagesExterieur
    }

    let imagesExterieurLinks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < imagesExterieur.length; i++) {
        const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(imagesExterieur[i], {
            folder: 'MecArtToyota/imagesExterieur'
        });

        imagesExterieurLinks.push({
            public_id: result.public_id,
            url: result.secure_url
        })
    }

    req.body.imagesExterieur = imagesExterieurLinks;
    req.body.user = req.user.id; 
   
    const product = await Product.create(req.body);
  
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        product
    })
})
```

[image: app.js]

Answer (score 0):

The Cloudinary SDKs contain a mechanism that allows for a degree of network tolerance in order to facilitate the upload of huge files. The `upload large` method uploads a big file in chunks to the cloud and is necessary for files larger than 100 MB.

For your instance you can try this. You can also declare the resource type as per the cloudinary documentation : https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#asset_types

```
const result = await 
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_large(imagesExterieur[i], {
     folder: 'MecArtToyota/imagesExterieur',
     chunk_size = 6000000
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL escape your whole Base64 input string. So for example, if your Base64 string starts with: `data:image/jpeg;base64`, it should be: `data%3Aimage%2Fjpeg%3Bbase64%2C`.